# Compress Python code

Tags: list, python-2.7, loops

How can I write the following loop in one line? Or is this not possible because of the if-statement?

```
a = listWithFancyIntegers

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] < 0:
        a[i] = 0
    else:
        a[i] = 1
```

What I do not want to have is a list of booleans.

I have already searched the web to check if I can use something like a Lambda expression but I didn't find anything that helped me. (Or I didn't understand it :D)

Thank you for your support.

Comment: `list_of_booleans = [value >= 0 for value in list_of_values]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [0 if n < 0 else 1 for n in listWithFancyIntegers]
```

**EDIT**

I prefer the code I wrote above, but here's another way:

```
a = [int(n >= 0) for n in listWithFancyIntegers]
```

or if you prefer `map` to list comprehension:

```
a = map(lambda n: int(n >= 0), listWithFancyIntegers)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a single line in Python

```
a = [0 if i < 0 else 1 for i in a]
```